# ¿Como accerder a ruta POST oauth/token con Laravel Passport?

Tags: php, laravel, passport, socialite

Estoy desarrollando una API, y estoy utilizando el paquete de Laravel Passport, en estos momentos estoy siguiendo este [tutorial](https://hivokas.com/api-authentication-via-social-networks-for-your-laravel-application) para poder incluir los auth mediante APIs de las redes sociales. Passport en mi proyecto ya esta funcionando correctamente, el problema es que quiero intentar acceder a la ruta que trae por defecto passport, que es /oauth/token y me tira un 404 en Postman.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Imagen de como prueba el EndPoint en el tutorial**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Tratando de probar el endpoint**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Mis Rutas**

**¿Como logro probar este endpoint?**  Desde ya muchas gracias y espero haber sido claro en la pregunta. Saludos.

Comment: Pareciera a simple vista que el problema es más de Apache que de Laravel.

Comment: @Shaz No creo que sea Apache, por que lo pensas? muchas gracias por contestar!

Comment: Normalmente Laravel envía una respuesta 404 un poco distinta, por eso lo digo, pero es solo mi impresión rápida.